# tidyr::pivot_longer to multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I need to convert a dataframe to longer form. for example, my dataframe will be like

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c("group1","group2"),
  x1 = c(3,4),
  x2 = c(5,6),
  y1 = c(7,8),
  y2 = c(9,10)
)
```

I need to convert it to

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  group = c("group1","group1","group2","group2"),
  num = c(1,2,1,2),
  x = c(3,5,4,6),
  y = c(7,9,8,10)
)
```

I want to use tidyr::pivot_longer but couldn't figure out names_pattern here. Am I on the right track?

```
df_2<-df%>%tidyr::pivot_longer(c("x1","x2","y1","y2"),
                               names_to = c("x","y"),
                               names_pattern = "")
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass regex in `names_pattern` -

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df,cols = -group, 
                    names_to = c('.value', 'num'), 
                    names_pattern = '([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)')

#  group  num       x     y
#  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 group1 1         3     7
#2 group1 2         5     9
#3 group2 1         4     8
#4 group2 2         6    10
```

`.value` has a special meaning in `pivot_longer` which suggests that part of the column name from original dataframe would be output dataframe's column name. The part is decided using `names_pattern` argument which provides a regex pattern in the form of capture group.

The first capture group `([a-zA-Z]+)` captures all the alphabets from the column names i.e `x` from `x1`, `x` from `x2`, `y` from `y1` and so on. As I have used `+` in the regex it will also work if you have column names which is more than 1 character (eg - `col1`, `col2` etc.). The second capture group is used to capture the numbers from the column name i.e `1` from `x1`, `2` from `x2` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `names_sep` with a regex lookaround

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols = -group, names_to = c(".value", "num"),
     names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=\\d)")
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  group  num       x     y
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 group1 1         3     7
2 group1 2         5     9
3 group2 1         4     8
4 group2 2         6    10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a way to solve this problem.using gather ,separate and spread functions

```
      df%>%
       gather(num,"x1","x2","y1","y2",-(group),value = 
       values)%>%
       separate(num,into=c("var",'val'),sep=1)%>%
       spread(key='var',value=values)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `reshape`

```
reshape(
  setNames(df, gsub("(\\d+)$", ".\\1", names(df))),
  direction = "long",
  idvar = "group",
  varying = -1,
  timevar = "n"
)
```

which gives

```
          group n x  y
group1.1 group1 1 3  7
group2.1 group2 1 4  8
group1.2 group1 2 5  9
group2.2 group2 2 6 10
```